# Which dialect should I use for MySQL 6 in Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

When selecting a dialect for Hibernate, the options for MySQL are:

- `MySQLDialect`
- `MySQL5Dialect`
- `MySQL55Dialect`
- `MySQL57Dialect`

The first option seems to be applicable to older versions than MySQL 5 (4 and below). `MySQL57Dialect` has been working fine for version 6.06 so far with me, but is it really entirely safe to use?

Comment: There is no released version of MySQL 6, or are you maybe talking about MySQL Connector/J 6, which BTW is also not a released version, just for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use `MySQL57Dialect`, as it extends all other [dialects](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/MySQL57Dialect.html).

But! Now MySQL was migrated to new release modelling and now preview release is MySQL v8.0.xx, and stable release is 5.7.xx. So MySQL v6 was dropped, and features developed for 6.0 are being incorporated into future releases. So I suggest you to use MySQL version 5.7.xx and `MySQL57Dialect` for it.