# how to execute sql statements inside spring boot controller?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, uuid

I want to execute sql statement inside my spring boot controller class with out defining any method in the jpa repository. The statement i want to use is

```
SELECT UUID();
```

This statement is database related and is not associated with a particular entity.

It would be nice if any one can provide solution for the execution of the above statement via

1. spring controller class
2. jpa repository (if recommended)

**update**

controller:

```
@Autowired
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@RequestMapping(value = "/UUID", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> getUUID() {
    String uuid = getUUID();
    return buildGuestResponse(uuid);
}

public String getUUID(){
    UUID uuid = (UUID)jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select UUID()", UUID.class);
    return uuid.toString();
}
```

Comment: explain more clearly by posting your code that is not working

Comment: Well first of all your not supposed to execute SQL statements inside your controller. Instead you should create a service class that implements the JPA repository interface.

Comment: Are you completely skipping the service/dao layer? This is not recommended approach.

Comment: what do you mean by This statement is database related and is not associated with a particular entity.? you don't want to use this uuid as primary key for entity?

Comment: @wafaahegazy yes, i don't wanna save it as primary key

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use JdbcTemplate in your code.

The bean you will need in your configuration class is:-

```
@Bean
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource)
{
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
```

And the code to run the query is:-

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate JdbcTemplate;

public String getUUID(){
    UUID uuid = (UUID)jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select UUID()", UUID.class);
    return uuid.toString();
}
```

or may be like this:-

```
public UUID getUUID(){
    UUID uuid = (UUID)jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select UUID()", UUID.class);
    return uuid;
}
```

Comment: tried it already , got org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT UUID()]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected end of statement

Comment: I tried with same code that I have shared above, it works perfect for me

Comment: might be some issue with your code, it works for me "select UUID()" also "SELECT UUID()"

Comment: i have updated the code, are u using mysql or hsqldb? i think select uuid() works in both cases

Comment: I am using h2 db

Comment: which mysql version?

Comment: i m using hsql and also mysql the lastest one

Comment: we are missing out something very simple I guess on your side, because I have tried myself. And May be you can try by cleaning the build folder and trying again

Comment: maybe the dialect ?

Comment: it has a different dialect

Comment: Refer here in the answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44460662/which-dialect-should-i-use-for-mysql-6-in-hibernate

Comment: still getting the same problem :( , i have to look deeper

Comment: :-( shouldn't be like this. but could be some minor stuff only

Comment: well the problem was with hsqldb. somehow SELECT UUID() is not a valid function in hsqldb but it works fine with MYSQL. I will accept your answer.

Comment: thats great news

Answer (score 3):

This is generally architecturally bad design to execute any SQL (do any persistence) on presentation layer (controller or view) in [JEE applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture).

The best option is make controller to use service layer, when service layer calling the persistence layer for: obtaining, saving or updating data.

In any case, you can use [Spring Data JDBC](https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/). Something like:

```
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

....
 UUID uuid = (UUID)jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT UUID()", UUID.class);
....
```

Comment: tied it before, gives me error ie can not resolve method "query(java.lang.string)

Comment: Java 9 and Spring 4 ?

Comment: java 8 spring boot 2

Comment: Then simply check your app config I think Spring aspect missing or something similar.

Comment: BTW, if you simply need a UUID you can use Java UUID class to generate.